# Sort files in dired by full path

Tags: emacs, dired

I am using find-name-dired to find multiple instances of files that all have the same name (call it foo.txt) but in different directories. I want the files listed by alphabetical order of file path. However, they're listed in what looks like a random order. Neither [dired-sort-menu](http://www.emacswiki.org/DiredSortMenu) nor [dired-sort-chiesa](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortBySizeAndExtension) will sort the output of find-name-dired, even though it will work on other dired buffers (whose format looks very similar). If I write the contents of the dired buffer to a file, I'm able to open a shell and submit the file to a sort command in the shell that uses the 9th field (the path) as a key. This produces output that looks right, but of course it's no longer a dired buffer.

Is there a way that I can

1. read in that externally sorted file and open it in dired "mode" (analogous to compilation mode),
2. sort the output of find-name-dired while still in dired mode, or
3. produce output from find-name-dired that's sorted the way I want from the beginning?

UPDATE:

Just to make things a bit more concrete, here's the current buffer:

```
/home/afrankel/Documents/emacs_test/:
find . \( -iname foo.txt \) -exec ls -ld \{\} \;
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 a/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 b/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 d/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 c/z/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 c/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 f/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 e/foo.txt

find finished at Fri Nov 30 17:00:41
```

Pressing "s" (which would sort most dired buffers) gives the error "Cannot sort this dired buffer".

I want the buffer to look like this:

```
/home/afrankel/Documents/emacs_test/:
find . \( -iname foo.txt \) -exec ls -ld \{\} \;
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 a/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 b/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 c/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 c/z/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 d/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 e/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 afrankel users        4 Nov 30 16:59 f/foo.txt

find finished at Fri Nov 30 17:00:41
```

Comment: I suppose you are using `find-name-dired` and not `dired-find-file` (which cannot search for files).

Comment: Yes, thanks! I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out how to do it using defadvice to automatically change the value of find-ls-option while I'm executing my new wrapper function (find-name-dired-sorted) and then to change it back to its original value.

```
(defadvice find-name-dired (around find-name-dired-around)
  "Advice: Sort output by path name."
  (let ((find-ls-option (list "-exec ls -ld {} \\; |sort --key=9")))
   ad-do-it))

(defun find-name-dired-sorted (dir pattern)
    "Sort the output of find-name-dired by path name."
    (interactive
     "DFind-name (directory): \nsFind-name (filename wildcard): ")
    (ad-activate 'find-name-dired)
    (find-name-dired dir pattern)
    (ad-deactivate 'find-name-dired))
```

Answer (score 3):

When you type <kbd>s</kbd> in a "normal" Dired buffer, Dired doesn't actually sort the buffer. What it does is to change the value of `dired-actual-switches` so that it does (or doesn't) contain the `-t` option ("sort by modification time") and then call `revert-buffer` which re-runs `ls` with the new options. This obviously doesn't work in a Dired buffer produced by running `find`.

What you need to do instead is to arrange to run `find` with the `-s` option:

```
 -s      Cause find to traverse the file hierarchies in lexicographical
         order, i.e., alphabetical order within each directory.
```

which you can do (for all `find-dired` commands) by evaluating

```
(setq find-program "find -s")
```

Comment: Sounded promising, but it didn't work for me. My "find" command told me that "-s" was an unknown predicate, and "man find" didn't mention a "-s" switch. Nor did "man ls" list anything promising. I'm still looking.

Comment: It looks like the "-s" switch exists only on the Mac OS X version of "find", not the Linux version.

Comment: Sorry about that! (It's not just Mac OS X, though: FreeBSD too.) Your solution in the other answers looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it manually via a temporary change to the configuration:

1. Run M-x customize-group find-dired.
2. Change the contents of the field "Find Ls Option" . It should initially read "-exec ls -ld {} \;". Append text to make it read "-exec ls -ld {} \; |sort --key=9". (In other words, sort by field 9, which is the full path treated as a single string.)
3. Set the option for the current session only.

UPDATE: It's better to do use defadvice, as I did in my other (later) answer.

Comment: It looks like I could use around-advice to implement this more neatly and efficiently.